# Can Azure Blob storage container name be made case insensitive?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have a picture server with lots of files serving the files over http. They are currently accessed through urls with the format

`http://pictures.example.com/Pictures/xx/yyyyyy/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.jpg`

We have a plan to move them to Azure blob storage and since the urls to the current pictures are used in several external systems we would like to keep the urls identical.

In Azure Blob storage the first part of the blob url is the name of the container. Our existing urls are named `Pictures/xxx`. Container names can, however, only have lowercase letters.

Do I have to create an Azure App Service just for url redirection or is there some way around this?

Comment: To solve this I will create an App Service with a wildcard route that will work as a proxy and stream the file from blob storage to the client.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Blob containers must be lower-case. Blob names can be mixed case.

There is no workaround to this, as it's part of the service.

You mentioned creating an app service for url redirection. Note that, if you choose to access your blobs directly, vs through your app service, you will not be able to perform any redirection.

More info on naming rules [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions).

Comment: I do want to highlight one thing in the link provided in David's answer: Blob names are case-sensitive. So if you save the blob with the name "MyFile.png" and if you access it via "myfile.png", you will get a 404 error.

Comment: Don't forget that if you are going to fake case-insensitivity by transforming all blob-names to lowercase or UPPERCASE in your client software, you should use UPPERCASE to avoid the Turkish-I problem instead of converting to lowercase (converting Unicode text to uppercase has a perfect mapping, converting to lowercase does not): https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/